# where can I find pygame.init() method in the installed pygame directory?

Tags: python, pygame

I can't find pygame.init() function.  please see what I did.

```
ckim@chan-ubuntu:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygame
pygame 1.9.4
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
>>> print (pygame.__file__)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/__init__.pyc
>>> pygame.init()
(6, 0)
```

so I searched under /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame but couldn't find the init() source code for module pygame. There I found base.so file which includes init ( checked with nm base.so). So is pygame not installed with all the source codes, some functions and types imlemented in C or C++ and provided by  .so files?

Comment: PyGame is wrapper for SDL 1.2 ([Simple DirectMedia Layer](https://www.libsdl.org/)) which is written in C. You can see C source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a big part of pygame is written in C.

[Here's](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/master/src_c/base.c#L265) the source of the `init` method of the pygame module.

I don't know what the compiled files look like in Linux since I don't have a Linux machine with pygame ready at the moment. But on Windows, you'll find e.g. `base.cp37-win32.pyd`, which is basically a DLL with the compiled C code.